# Layout issue with Viewpages in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

i work with viewpages i have 3 and i got this in every page.
i dont find the error to get this output[image: error[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBibf.png)

there ist a white stripe at the top and buttom. i dont find anything to fix it. here is my code:

and the story.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;



public class Story1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story1, container, false);

        Button _play = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);

        _play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
       });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jeravare.hypralyne.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: issue is in activity's layout , fragment has done nothing wrong, he is innocent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the fragment layout.

You can change this:

```
android:layout_width="368dp"
android:layout_height="495dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
```

to this:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp" // you can remove this if you don't need a space at the top
```

Comment: have added the main